# Web API 2 OData = $format not working: the request is always ignored

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a Web API OData project and everything is working great. I'm now trying to return xml instead of JSON using the $format parameter, as opposed to specifying a header request, and it is not working. I've tried these approaches:

```
http://localhost:3845/api/Customer?$format=application/xml
http://localhost:3845/api/Customer?$format=xml
http://localhost:3845/api/Customer?$format=application/xml;odata.metadata=full
```

All without success. This article says that it is possible: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/03/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0/

I have updated all of my NuGet packages, but it seems that the request is always ignored, and instead I get JSON every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the ATOM format (XML) is only a technical committee specification instead of an OASIS standard for the OData V4 protocol, the ATOM format is disabled in the ODataLib from the [version 6.3.0](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/6.3.0).

The correct way to ask the OData V4 service to respond in XML is as follows:

```
GET http://localhost:3845/api/Customer?$format=application/atom+xml
```

or set the header `Accept` to `application/atom+xml`. But due to the reason mentioned above, it doesn't work for Web API OData V4.

Answer (score 0):

To support `$format=xml` and `$format=json`, add the following configuration:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.AddQueryStringMapping("$format", "json", "application/json");
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.AddQueryStringMapping("$format", "xml", "application/xml");
```