# OData v4 Web API support for ATOM response

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata, atom-feed

I am building an OData Web Service using WebAPI and OData v4.

I was able to get the service to return XML using the trick:

```
IList <ODataMediaTypeFormatter> oDataFormatters = ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create();
config.Formatters.InsertRange(0, oDataFormatters);
```

However, ATOM is a more preferred output than XML. Is this at all possible or are there plan to make it possible anytime soon?

I have read that an OData v4 service must allow for JSON response but can also allow for ATOM. However, I simply haven't been able to configure my WebAPI to return ATOM.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this thread: [Web API 2 OData = $format not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130017/web-api-2-odata-format-not-working)

As Yi Ding writes in the answer, "Since the ATOM format (XML) is only a technical committee specification instead of an OASIS standard for the OData V4 protocol, the ATOM format is disabled in the ODataLib from the version 6.3.0". I believe it won't work in Web API 2.2 either, until ATOM is formally approved by OASIS.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. Yeah I've read answers like the one you posted, i just hoped there was maybe some way to configure it anyway, as i got it to return XML even if OData4 doesn't support XML.

Comment: Hi Vagif, do you have any idea of the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494246/odata-client-with-cookie